# How are SQL Server-based processing features different than Kinetica db?

Tags: sql-server, gpu, kinetica

I'm moving into a data-intensive financial project where I will be leveraging GPU processing for performing simulations.

However I'm curious about some new database technologies such as [www.kinetica.com](http://www.kinetica.com) which tout GPU-based processing.  However SQL Server has [GPU accelerated OLAP functions](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/409163/use-of-gpu-to-accelerate-olap-and-sql-aggregate-functions) and some new [AI-baseline-based structure](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2017/04/19/delivering-ai-with-data-the-next-generation-of-microsofts-data-platform/).

How different are these SQL Server-based features than those promoted by Kinetica and would it be worth rearchitecting the data model away from SQL Server?